# How to Collect nodeItem to list/map with groovy?

Tags: xml, groovy

I have xml and I have to transform it. How to make it correctly.
How to parse and group xml with groovy. Or please give advice me.

```
<getDataResponse>
    <dataItem> 
          <osVer>1.1</osVer>
          <mobileVer>iPad7</mobileVer>
          <email>mail</email>
          <id>1</id> 
    </dataItem>
    <dataItem> 
          <osVer>1.18</osVer>
          <mobileVer>iPhone5</mobileVer>
          <email>mail</email>
          <id>1</id>
   </dataItem>
</getDataResponse>
```

I write this code to collect my data:

```
 def res = []
 for(item in dataResponse.children()){
    res << item.findAll{
        it.name().equals('osVer') || 
                    it.name().equals('mobileVer')
    }.inject([:]){
        map, ch -> map + [(ch.name()) : ch.text()]
    }
}
res.join()
```

I want to get this output:

```
<getDataResponse>
    <dataItem> 
          <info>[osVer:1.1, mobileVer: iPad7]
                [osVer:1.8, mobileVer: iPhone5]</info>
          <email>mail</email>
          <id>1</id> 
    </dataItem>         
</getDataResponse>
```

Comment: And what output do you get?

Comment: I get [osVer: 1.1, mobileVer: iPad7][osVer:1.8, mobileVer: iPhone5]. But when element dataItem not include mobileVer&osVer I get: [:][osVer:1.8, mobileVer: iPhone5].